# Showing that the vector space $V$ cannot be generated.

Tags: linear-algebra

Simply asking how  can someone show that the vector space $V$ of all polynomials on a field, say $K$ cannot be generated with any finite set of vectors?

I don't know where to tackle the problem. :(

Thank you.

Comment: In any finite set of polynomials, there is one of largest degree.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Ops! Yes the second one is correct. I will fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that it could be, for vectors (polynomials) $p_1,\ldots, p_n$.  Let $$m=\text{max}\{\text{deg}(p):p=a_1p_1+\ldots+a_np_n:a_1,\ldots,a_n\in K\}.$$
Surely a polynomial of degree $m+1$ exists in $V$.  This is a contradiction.

Comment: I'd have written $m=\max\{\deg p_i\}$.

Comment: @YACP I was thinking we'd still have to establish that no polynomial can exceed that degree in $V$ for the contradiction.  But it is a simple proof.  Same diff.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to show that the infinite family $\{X^n : n\geq 0\}$ is linearly independent.